# Set compiler flags and Openmp for Mingw64 in Matlab 2015b

Tags: c, matlab, mex, compiler-flags, mingw-w64

I have Matlab 2015b with MinGW 4.9.2 compiler (Distributor: TDM-GCC) on Win7 64bit. I have also a 'C' program, running with no warning or exception as a ***MEX*** file. Now I need to use Openmp library to parallelize its execution in the Mex file but I can't find out how to give the instructions to the compiler (it has no problem using Openmp as a 'C' program).
A similar problem I've experienced with optimization flag that I use running that program as a normal 'C' execution. I set *-O3* in `c = mex.getCompilerConfigurations`, `Details`, `OptimizationFlag` but I get the same time executing the mex file with or without that flag set in that way.
So the question is how can I give **openmp and optimization flag** to the mingw compiler in Matlab?

Comment: Based on my experience, it's almost always a good idea to use mex only to link, and use makefile to compile. In the makefile you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Do you have any examples on how to do it, please?